# Warnings while using [ngClass]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I have component called `contact-list`. This component is used display list of contacts with there photo like this:

[image]

- As shown in the image, By default i have highlighted first contact(i,e `background -color` and `text-color` of list-item changed).
- And i am displaying this selected contacts details on right side by using another component called `display` like this:

[image]

Here is `contact-list` component CODE:

**HTML**

```
 <mat-selection-list>
    <mat-list-option [ngClass]="{selected : contact.fullName == currentContact.fullName}"  *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
       <a mat-list-item (click)="onSelect(contact)"><img src="{{contact?.pictureUrl}}" > <span>{{ contact?.fullName }}</span> </a>
    </mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>
```

**TS**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input , Output, ViewChild } from 
   '@angular/core';
 import { IContact } from 'src/app/models/app.models';

@Component({
  selector: 'btn-contact-list',
  templateUrl: './contact-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-list.component.scss'],
   })

 export class ContactListComponent {

  @Input()
    public contacts:  IContact[] ;
  @Output() public select: EventEmitter<{}> = new EventEmitter(); 

  public currentContact: IContact;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
   if (this.contacts && this.contacts.length > 0) {
     this.currentContact = this.contacts[0];
     this.select.emit(this.currentContact);
   }
  }

  public onSelect(contact: IContact): void {
    this.currentContact = contact; 
    this.select.emit(contact); 
   }

 }
```

This Scenario is working fine for me: But in the console i am getting this warning:
What's wrong with the `[ngClass]`?
[image]

Comment: try writing contact?.fullName

Comment: I have already tried your answer, still no result..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have additional check of `undefined` of object before you access the property of an `object`. You can modify your code as following -

```
<mat-list-option 
     [ngClass]="{selected : contact && currentContact && contact.fullName == currentContact.fullName}"  
     *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
```

Comment: Now i am unable to highlight the first `contact` by default...:)

Comment: It means you did not set `currentContact` by default.

Comment: How to set `currentContact` as default?

Comment: Previously it was fine, after implementing api i am facing this issue..:)